# spring data null arguments

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to implement the service for a rest controller that takes optional filter parameters like first name, last name, age, etc. I want to use a JpaRepository method like below. The problem is, if a parameter is null then no records are found.

When a argument is null i do not want filtering to occur on that field. Is there a way to implement this out of the box with JpaRepository?

```
Page<Customer> findByLastNameAndByFirstNameAndByAge(String lastName, String firstName, int age, Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html) Table 2.2 indicates you could use something similar to findByLastnameOrFirstnameOrAge, which would ignore the null values.

IF that doesn't get what you want, you'll have to do it with a Specification (see Section 3 of the above document).

Comment: The Or will not work since i need a combination of the filters, but it looks like Specification will do the trick. Thank you!